# Is there a way to create a sky-sphere instead of a skybox in Unity3D?

Tags: 3d, unity, skybox

In a 3D game, how can I make a sky background seen at the horizon? I tried adding a texture to the skybox but since it's a box it looks horrible.

When I'm not using a texture it's not notable that it is actually a box so it looks better.

I can imagine doing the same with a huge sphere but I imagine there is a proper way of doing it, so I thought I would ask.

Comment: Did you create that skybox as described in the [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-UseSkybox.html)?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you're not applying lighting to the skybox.  It should be full brightness without any lights.  Lights make box edges visible even without textures, so you're probably not doing that.

Second, your choice of texture needs to be seamless and well chosen as a skybox texture(s).  If you're rendering a literal sky *box* then the textures need to also be created with knowledge that they're mapped to a box and be distorted in such a way that it appears non-boxy near the seams, essentially the same as a cubemap.

There are more advanced ways of rendering skyboxes which give even better results, but that's the gist of the basic version.  Here's a [fixed-function OpenGL tutorial](http://sidvind.com/wiki/Skybox_tutorial) that will maybe explain things better than I did.